# Mathematical literature wiki

Tags: books, reference-request

Does there exist, either still in development or already on on-line, anything like a wiki-type tool designed for mathematicians and students studying monographs and texts and journal articles---a place for readers, say, to flag typos, correct mistakes, fill gaps, provide shortcuts, supply missing references and  indicate progress postdating the original publication?

Comment: There is a question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2147/
 on helpful math resources on the web. I suggest if something like this should exist and was not already suggested there, it could be suggested there. And, this can be closed, say as too localised or not a real question (depnding on interpretation).

Comment: Try the nLab.  I doubt they'll complain if you make a few pages like that.

Comment: Thank you Scott for that very sharp suggestion.  (nLab had not previously shown up on my radar.)